# Loading data into Snowflake with ',' in the text field

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load a csv file using the COPY INTO command. Let's say I have a field called Company Name.  In my data file, a company name with a command "Hello, Inc." will fail to load.

I am using these options

on_error = 'skip_file'
FILE_FORMAT = ( TYPE = CSV, RECORD_DELIMITER='\n' );

What other option do I use in the COPY INTO command so that the ',' in the data does not confuse Snowflake since the field delimiter is defaulted to be ','

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```sql
  file_format = (type = csv field_optionally_enclosed_by='"')
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-copy-into.html

Default is 'none', so setting `field_optionally_enclosed_by` to `"` will fix this issue.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-csv

Comment: Thanks for letting me know it worked, please accept the answer if it was useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

file_format = (type = csv field_optionally_enclosed_by='"')